# How to change the brightness on iPhone (using private APIs)

Tags: iphone, settings, brightness

I want to make an app similar to SBSettings (a quick settings application on Cydia) because developers can't jailbreak their devices. Can someone tell me how to change the screen brightness? **It doesnt need to be approved by Apple**, so it can use private APIs if needed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What makes you think developers can't jail break? I always keep one of my devices jail-broken to access the file system.

Comment: And why make the effort so short before iOS 5 is released when it's already public information that the screen brightness control is now a public API?

Comment: @Manu it says in the iOS developer agreement that you can't "hack" your device or modify any system files.

Comment: @OleBegemann I was not aware of that... I guess I'll wait until then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `[[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:0.1]` in iOS 5.0